# Pivotal-mysqlweb : PCF Auto login issues

Tags: cloud-foundry

I am not able to view any tables in the PCF . The Auto login fails. I am using the SERVICE: Data-Services MySQLPLAN: Data-Services MySQL Database and I have a service Name only .

My yaml file is as follows

```
---
applications:
- name: pivotal-mysqlweb
memory: 1024M
instances: 1
random-route: true
path: ./target/PivotalMySQLWeb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
services:
- myservicename
env:
JAVA_OPTS: -Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/urandom
SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: cloud
```

And the application.cloud properties is as follows

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.database=MYSQL
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

# Naming strategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy

# Use spring.jpa.properties.* for Hibernate native properties (the prefix is
# stripped before adding them to the entity manager)

# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

And the log trace from the PCF logs where it is deployed as an App

```
2017-11-21T11:31:57.759+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2017-11-21 06:01:57.759 INFO 14 --- [io-8080-exec-10] c.p.p.m.controller.LoginController : {"data-services-MySQL":[{
2017-11-21T11:31:57.759+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] "credentials": {
2017-11-21T11:31:57.759+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] "uri": "mysql://ds_0d129acceb:roolq...:3306/ds_0d129acceb?verifyServerCertificate=true&useSSL=true&requireSSL=true"
2017-11-21T11:31:57.759+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] },
2017-11-21T11:31:57.760+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] "syslog_drain_url": null,
2017-11-21T11:31:57.760+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] "volume_mounts": [
2017-11-21T11:31:57.760+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] ],
2017-11-21T11:31:57.760+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] "label": "data-services-MySQL",
2017-11-21T11:31:57.760+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] "provider": null,
2017-11-21T11:31:57.760+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] "plan": "Data-Services MySQL Database",
2017-11-21T11:31:57.760+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] "name": "myservicename",
2017-11-21T11:31:57.760+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] "tags": [
2017-11-21T11:31:57.760+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] "MySQL",
2017-11-21T11:31:57.760+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] "Database storage"
2017-11-21T11:31:57.760+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] ]
2017-11-21T11:31:57.760+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] }]}
2017-11-21T11:31:57.772+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2017-11-21 06:01:57.767 INFO 14 --- [io-8080-exec-10] c.p.p.m.controller.LoginController : Login : Login{username='null', password='null', url='null', schema='null'}
2017-11-21T11:31:57.772+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2017-11-21 06:01:57.767 INFO 14 --- [io-8080-exec-10] c.p.p.m.controller.LoginController : Auto Login via VCAP_SERVICES Failed - null
```

What could be the problem here ?

Comment: Do you created table in database?

Comment: Yeah  the tables are auto-created using the property from appication.properties . We are able to retrieve the records but we do not have the UI to query and view  the tables and records.

Comment: You can try with MySQL community software to query and view the tables and records.